# Counting intersections from multiple shapefiles in counties?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, batch, loop, waterways

I have several polygon shapefiles of counties in 6 US states. I also have three shapefiles of country-wide "impaired waterways" a line, a polgyon, and  a point feature classes.

What I want is a count of the number of the total geometries (ALL of the impaired waterways) that are within each COUNTY.

Is there a way I can do this in a loop or a batch? I can understand some code, but I do not code myself (yet! working on it!), but is there a tool somewhere that I can use to accomplish this goal?

I know I could split each county shapefile into individual shapefiles and then do a select by location on the three impaired waterways layers, and then get three separate totals to add together, but this will be immensely time consuming, as I have 654 total counties, and I would have to do it three times, once for each waterway layer.

Comment: So, do you want all the waterways for each county in its own shapefile? Or is it that you want the County name transferred to the waterways in a single shape file? Is it just the 'count' you're after... there is a simple way.

Comment: it is just the count! I just want a count of the total impaired waterways (including all three shapefiles: line, point and polygon) in each county.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to transfer your attributes from your counties to your points, lines and polygons. To do this you will need to use an overlay operator like [Intersect](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Intersect/00080000000p000000/) or [Identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000n000000) (both work roughly the same way but with subtle differences - look at the pictures on the links). I think Intersect will be the best but at least have a look at both.

Points, lines and polygons can't be merged into a single feature class... but their attribute tables can. Use [Table Select](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000007000000) to export the attribute tables into a dbf or geodatabase table. At this point you can use [summary statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) to get the count of each of point, line and poly.

Then merge the tables using [merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000055000000) to get the count of all features, regardless of geometry type.

Now to achieve a count use [summary statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with a `statistics field` of FID/OBJECTID (depending on whether it's a dbf or geodatabase) `statistics type` of `COUNT` and `case field` of your `county name` (or `county FID` if names are not unique)..

You can now [join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002n000000) the summary table onto your counties and see the total count of all records within.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I am going to combine the county attributes with each of the three geometries separately (using intersect or identity) and then merge and count the features?

Comment: That's correct, because the geometry types are different you can only merge the tables.. note: the only important attributes are FID/OBJECTID and County Name/ID; because the tables might differ slightly in their attribution you could consider making a new table (with only the required attributes) and use append (no test) to import the records into it - but there's more steps so consider that if you're having difficulty with merging the tables.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you for explaining it so clearly!